# VS UnitTest - Thread was Being Aborted

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unit-testing, timeout

I have a set of Unit Tests **run in parallel** (*this is important, it works fine if the tests are run single-threaded*) which makes calls to WebClient to download a resource that consistently takes over 30 seconds to return, and this causes the Unit Test to forcefully exit with one of the following two messages:

> Thread was being aborted.
>
> The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded.

I have tried setting the `[Timeout]` attribute, various `app.config` settings, including even creating an `EventWaitHandle` to make the unit test thread wait on the WebClient thread, with no luck.  I checked the Test Timeouts settings under the Test Settings, and it is set to the default of 30 minutes.

---

**Edit 2:**

As indicated by @peer, this is a known bug in the VS.Net Test Framework: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/587390/threadabortexception-when-running-two-tests-in-parallel-one-taking-40-seconds

**Edit:**

Here is the simplest scenario which will reproduce the problem.  Can you make these Unit Tests run to completion, and if so, how?  **These tests must be run in parallel!**  Start a new Visual Studio Unit Test project, and use the following settings and Test Method code.  When you run, make sure they are actually running in parallel (i.e., you will need a processor with multiple cores, and check that they are running simultaneously.  I have found that to get them to run in parallel, I have to apply all the settings, then close the project and re-open it again before the parallelization will apply).

**Local.testsettings** (add `parallelTestCount="#"`, whatever applies to your processor):

```
<Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
<Deployment enabled="false" />
<Execution parallelTestCount="4">
  <TestTypeSpecific />
  <AgentRule name="Execution Agents">
  </AgentRule>
</Execution>
```

**TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings** (comment out the `DataCollectors`):

```
<Description>These are test settings for Trace and Test Impact.</Description>
<Execution parallelTestCount="0">
  <TestTypeSpecific />
  <AgentRule name="Execution Agents">
    <!--<DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/SystemInfo/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.SystemInfo.SystemInfoDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.SystemInfo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="System Information">
      </DataCollector>
      <DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/HttpProxy/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector.HttpProxyCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="ASP.NET Client Proxy for IntelliTrace and Test Impact">
      </DataCollector>
      <DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/TestImpact/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector.TestImpactDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="Test Impact">
      </DataCollector>
      <DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/TraceDebugger/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector.TraceDebuggerDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="IntelliTrace">
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>-->
  </AgentRule>
</Execution>
```

**UnitTest1.cs** (first unit test, sleeps 35 seconds):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Thread.Sleep(35000);
    // in default unit test settings, this line will never be reached
    Console.WriteLine("TestMethod1");
}
```

**UnitTest2.cs** (second unit test, sleeps 35 seconds):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    Thread.Sleep(35000);
    // in default unit test settings, this line will never be reached
    Console.WriteLine("TestMethod2");
}
```

If you have the parallelization correctly setup, you will find that both tests will fail, with a `ThreadAbortException`, with either of the two messages presented at the top.  How can I tell these methods to run longer than 30 seconds??

Comment: I think the right thing to do is to use a mocking framework like Rhino or Moq to Mock the web service. Calling Ws in a Unit test is not a good practice

Comment: @MikeGoatly: I figured out I was missing a piece. It works fine for me, until I make it parallel execution, then I get the error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should go to menu: Test -> Edit Test Setting -> current test config

Go to the tab: Test Timeouts

Change the timeout to any time you like.

Comment: Your test works fine. The most likely problem is that the config used, is not the config you are editing. Try to change the timeout to 1 second en see if it end after 1 second.

Comment: @peer: Discovered what makes it quit working.  When I run the test single-threaded, it works fine for me as well. When I run multiple tests in parallel, then I start getting the `Thread was being aborted` message again.

Comment: It is a bug in the vs.net test framework: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/587390/threadabortexception-when-running-two-tests-in-parallel-one-taking-40-seconds

Comment: Marking yours as answered for now, since you have the answer in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your test settings are configured with a timeout?

[image]

Comment: makes sense, that's the default.

Comment: Discovered what makes it quit working. When I run the test single-threaded, it works fine for me as well. When I run multiple tests in parallel, then I start getting the Thread was being aborted message again

Answer (score 1):

I also just got this with a multi threaded test.

The test was moving on to the assert before the work in the task was done. The assert failed and the test harness aborted the task.

I added a wait loop until the task was complete and everything worked like a charm.

-Chris